# How can I find questions from new users?

Tags: support, questions, new-users

To be able to help new users as fast as possible, I would like to know where I can find their questions in the ocean of unanswered ones, and maybe within a specific tag.

Any ideas?

Comment: My first reaction was "why prioritize new users over existing users?" but given the frosty reception that newbies often come to Meta to complain about, this might be an interesting thing to think about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Review/First Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions) page to find a list of first questions posted by new users.  This page isn't geared towards *answering* questions though, so I don't know how useful it will be.  It might work if you hide ignored tags, so you're not swimming in a sea of questions that don't interest you.

Comment: You can also filter to specific *tags*: `http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions?s=1&pagesize=15&filter=all&tag=<INPUT YOUR PREFERRED TAGS HERE>`

Comment: @Gaffi That's much better.

Comment: Thanks! I actually use the link above quite regularly.